# How can I make my text animation run in a certain order and start in the middle of the page using CSS?

Tags: html, css

1. When the text animation starts how can I get the text animation to run in the order listed below unlike from line one, line three and then line two? For example, I wanted each line to display in the order below.

   - Welcome To My Digital Portfolio
   - My name is Liam Docherty
   - I'm a front-end web developer from London.
2. How can I get the text animation to start from the middle of the page and not swipe across from the left?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/240265L6/1/)

```
<!-- Intro Section -->
  <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <p class="main1">Welcome To My Digital Portfolio</p>
          <p>My name is Liam Docherty</p>
          <p>I'm a front-end web developer from London.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems a simple `text-align: center` won't work for centering the text without messing up your animation, you can set an explicit width for your text (whatever the width happens to be with this font/size combination) and then use `auto` left and right margins to center it.

Then, give each sentence a separate animation that has an `animation-delay` that is equal to the total length of each animation before it. In the `animation` shorthand I use below, it's the second number that is the delay. The first number (`4s` in each case) is the `animation-duration`.

Each animation will set the text to go from 0 width to its actual, final width.

But since the default style is 0 width with this approach, set an `animation-fill-mode` of `forwards` to make sure the text doesn't disappear after it's done animating.

```
<p class="main1">Welcome To My Digital Portfolio</p>
<p class="main2">My name is Liam Docherty</p>
<p class="main3">I'm a front-end web developer from London.</p>
```

```
p {
 color: white;
 font-family: "Helvetica";
 font-size: 1.3em;
 margin: 10px auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 0px
}
.main1 {
  animation: type 4s 0s forwards steps(60, end);
}
.main2 {
  animation: type2 4s 4s forwards steps(60, end);
}
.main3 {
  animation: type3 4s 8s forwards steps(60, end);
}
@keyframes type{
 from { width: 0; }
 to { width: 430px; }
}
@keyframes type2{
 from { width: 0; }
 to { width: 224px; }
}
@keyframes type3{
 from { width: 0; }
 to { width: 364px; }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/240265L6/4/).

Comment: Fantastic in-depth answer! Thanks for your time, nice to see someone who is posting a good answer like this to help me develop my understanding.